# Base64 background image in multiple lines?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to put **base64** background image in multiple lines instead of one long line? If so, how?

My current body CSS is:

```css
body {
  background-color:  #FFFFFF;
  background-image:  url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAgAAAAICAIAAABLbSncAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAAAZSURBVBhXY/iABP4jAQYqSiCbi2wsA/UkAIeAuaFCb0TzAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC);
  background-repeat: repeat;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just try breaking your base64 data in separate lines? You have no enclosing quotes or whatsoever, so just try inserting a \n somewhere.

Comment: @Cyrille - Because `\n` (a new line separator) is just not enough - see answer bellow.

Comment: Didn't read anywhere that you had tried that ;) Glad you found a solution though.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Put your code between quotes and put a backslash before breaking to new line.

```css
body {
    background-color:  #FFFFFF;
    background-image:  url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUg\
    AAAAgAAAAICAIAAABLbSncAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQ\
    U1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADs\
    MAAA7DAcdvqGQAAAAZSURBVBhXY/iABP4j\
    AQYqSiCbi2wsA/UkAIeAuaFCb0TzAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC');
    background-repeat: repeat;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: This causes Firefox's CSS rule inspector to break. Even though the page renders normally, the developer tools are broken in Firefox 57.