# Is it possible to concatinate two strings inside a CSS rule?

Tags: css, string-concatenation

I'm trying to split the following CSS rule into two lines:

```
background: url("data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBR‌​AA7") 0 0 repeat;
```

I tried splitting the url base64 string into two sub strings to avoid going over the line length according to the [style guide for an open source project called PDF.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/wiki/Style-Guide).

I tried doing "xxxx" + "xxxx" and that didn't work.

So I was wondering if anyone has tried to do that before or if it is even possible to concat two strings in a css rule?

Comment: Do you think that style guide even applies in this case?

Comment: @WesleyMurch Good question. I have noticed other instances of CSS rules in the file that I'm trying to modify where the rules were longer than the suggested guideline. I wanted to check if it was possible at all. So I think in this case the style guide doesn't apply.

Comment: Well, add your own answer with your new-found knowledge - ref. http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/

Comment: Ok sweet. It works. Thanks for the help. I will add my own answer then.

Comment: Never forget guidelines are just that, guidelines.

Comment: You *can* concatenate string values in CSS - there is no operator for it, just separate them with whitespace. (I don't believe it applies to "strings" within the `url()` function though.)

Comment: @BoltClock I don't agree. String concatenation (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concatenation) does not equal escaping a newline (whitespace) in a string.

Comment: @Mido: No, seriously, that is how you concatenate strings in CSS. http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/dF6h3 I'm just addressing your question.

Answer (score 1):

According to the CSS2 specification http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/syndata.html#strings, there is no concat operation. However, you can split strings on multiple lines for aesthetic reasons.

> It is possible to break strings over several lines, for aesthetic or
>   other reasons, but in such a case the newline itself has to be escaped
>   with a backslash ().

So the solution to my problem would be:

```
  background: url("data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAA\
                   LAAAAAABAAEAAAIBR‌​AA7") 0 0 repeat;
```

[Which is kind of related to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11398205/base64-background-image-in-multiple-lines)